# Show that the sequence is convergent $\frac{(1)(3)(5)\dots(2n-1)}{(2)(4)(6)\dots(2n)}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, monotone-functions

$\mathbf{Question:}$ Show that $\frac{(1)(3)(5)\dots(2n-1)}{(2)(4)(6)\dots(2n)}$ is convergent where $n\in \mathbb{N}$

$\mathbf{My\ attempt:}$
Let $a_n = \frac{2n-1}{2n}$ and let $f(n) = a_n$

$$
f(n)=\frac{2n-1}{2n} = 1-\frac{1}{2n}
$$

$$
f'(n) = \frac{1}{2n^2}
$$

As $f'(n)>0$, it is a strictly increasing sequence

And $\frac{2n-1}{2n} >0$, therefore it is bounded below

But according to the Monotone convergence theorem, this sequence is divergent instead of convergent?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The sequence you are referring to $a_n$ is not the same as the sequence in your question. So saying anything about $a_n$ is not of much help.

Comment: Your given sequence (based on your question) is 
$$a_n=\frac{1\cdot 3 \cdot 5 \dotsb (2n-1)}{2 \cdot 4 \cdot \cdot 6\dotsb(2n)}=\frac{1\cdot \color{red}{2} \cdot 3 \cdot \color{red}{4} \cdot 5 \dotsb (2n-1) \cdot \color{red}{(2n)}}{2^2 \cdot 4^2 \cdot 6^2\dotsb(2n)^2}=\frac{(2n)!}{2^{2n}(n!)^2}$$

Comment: There's a wrinkle in terminology that makes the wording of this question a little unfortunate. The limit being asked about that of an [infinite product](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3735972/show-that-the-sequence-is-convergent#3735977), $\ \displaystyle\prod_{i=1}^\infty\left(1-\frac{1}{2i}\right)\ $, whose limit happens to be zero. When the limit of an infinite product with no zero terms is nevertheless zero, it is said to "diverge to zero", even though the *sequence* $\ a_n\ $ defined by $\ \displaystyle a_n=\prod_{i=1}^n\left(1-\frac{1}{2i}\right)\ $ is actually convergent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We define:

$$a_n=\prod_{k=1}^n\bigg(\frac{2k-1}{2k}\bigg)$$
Then, $$a_{n+1}=\prod_{k=1}^{n+1}\bigg(\frac{2k-1}{2k}\bigg)=a_n\cdot\frac{2n+1}{2n+2}$$

$$\implies \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\frac{2n+1}{2n+2}<1$$

$$\implies a_{n+1}<a_{n}$$
$$(a_n)_{n\in \Bbb N} \text{ converges}$$

For boundedness, observe that $a_1=\frac12$ and each element of our product is non-negative, thusly $0<a_j\leq \frac12$ for each $a_j$

Comment: You still need to show boundedness as well to claim convergence. Also the last line should be $a_{n+1}<a_n$.

Comment: Good spot, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Since
$\dfrac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}
=\dfrac{2n+1}{2n+2}
=1-\dfrac{1}{2n+2}
$,

$\begin{array}\\
f(n, m)
&=\dfrac{a_{m+1}}{a_n}\\
&=\prod_{k=n}^m \dfrac{a_{k+1}}{a_k}\\
&=\prod_{k=n}^m (1-\dfrac{1}{2k+2})\\
g(n, m)
&=\ln(f(n, m))\\
&=\sum_{k=n}^m \ln(1-\dfrac{1}{2k+2})\\
&\lt\sum_{k=n}^m -\dfrac{1}{2k+2}
\qquad\text{since }\ln(1-x) < -x\\
&\to -\infty
\qquad\text{as } m \to \infty\\
\text{so}\\
f(n, m)
&\to 0
\qquad\text{as } m \to \infty\\
\end{array}
$